# How to extract rows from a log file using Windows command line tools or batch file?

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file

I would like to extract certain rows from a log file using native Windows command line tools or batch file (.bat). Here's a sample log file:

```
2009-12-07 14:32:38,669 INFO  Sample log
2009-12-07 14:32:43,029 INFO  Sample log
2009-12-07 14:32:45,841 DEBUG Sample log
2009-12-07 14:32:45,841 DEBUG Sample log
2009-12-07 14:32:52,029 WARN  Sample log
2009-12-07 14:32:52,466 INFO  Sample log
```

How to extract and print lines which have tag "WARN"? How to do this with PowerShell?

Comment: [Print line if contains word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881159/print-line-if-contains-word)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way:

```
findstr WARN log.txt
```

More complex:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=, " %i in (log.txt) do @if "%l"=="WARN" echo %i %j %m

OUTPUT:
2009-12-07 14:32:52 Sample log
```

Comment: I believe you should use " this way `findstr "WARN" log.txt`

Answer (score 7):

you can do it with PowerShell using select-stirng :

```
select-String  WARN  *.log
```

Comment: This is the best and the right answer, but requirements often expand and sooner or later we all end up here:  

    `gci . -r *.log | % { gc $_.fullname | ? { $_ -cmatch "WARN" }}`

i.e.,

    `get-childitem . -recurse *.log | foreach { get-content $_.fullname | ? { $_ -cmatch "WARN" }}`

Answer (score 2):

If PowerShell (as suggested by Alon) isn't an option, maybe Logparser will fulfill for your needs: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways, findstr/find like what others show you. Or you can use vbscript

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFile= objArgs(0)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,"WARN") > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo strLine
    End If 
Loop
```

save as mygrep_warn.vbs and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo mygrep_warn.vbs myfile.log
```

Other methods, if you can download stuff and use [GNU *nix tools ported to win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)

```
C:\test>grep -i "warn" file
2009-12-07 14:32:52,029 WARN  Sample log

C:\test>gawk "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/warn/" file
2009-12-07 14:32:52,029 WARN  Sample log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-EventLog -LogName application -EntryType warning
```

and export the output as you like

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the original DOS "find" command, it's pretty crappy though:

```
c:>find " WARN " filename.log

---------- FILENAME.LOG
2009-12-07 14:32:52,029 WARN  Sample log

c:>
```

You can't use wildcards in the filename either.

Comment: you can with `findstr`, though, and you got regular expressions—sort of. `find` isn't the only thing out there :-)

Comment: I never use it any more unless I'm using a bare-bones Windows machine and have no alternative.  I've never heard of findstr before.  That looks somewhat usable!