# Batch file to search for string and return line

Tags: batch-file

I know very basic (Windows) batch scripting, and this is way out of my league - hopefully I can get some help here.

I have multiple text files of the same file name in folders with the naming convention yyyy-mm (eg. C:\folder\yyyy-mm\file.txt)

I would like to write a script to go into all file.txt, search for a unique ID in the file always at the beginning of the line (may or may not recur in the different months), return/append the folder name (yyyy-mm) at the front of the whole line that matches the search into a new text file, and move on to the next month.

ie.

> C:\folder\2014-05\file.txt contains line "ID123 foo bar" among other lines
>
> C:\folder\2014-05\file.txt contains line "ID123 bar foo" among other lines
>
> output file for a search on ID123 would be
>
> 2014-04 ID123 foo bar
>
> 2014-05 ID123 bar foo

Would this be simpler with some other language? I am familiar with Excel VBA, but not quite so with filesystemobjects within VB.

There are no other sub-folders to be concerned of, so I am not worried about recognizing the correct sub-folders and just do loop over all sub-folders.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract rows from a log file using Windows command line tools or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107555/how-to-extract-rows-from-a-log-file-using-windows-command-line-tools-or-batch-fi)

Comment: [Print line if contains word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881159/print-line-if-contains-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you something similar to what you ask.

```
findstr /s /b "ID123" file.txt
```

It will recurse though the folders looking for and searching in each `file.txt`

Comment: add a `>newfile.txt` to store the output to a txtfile.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here..

http://ss64.com/nt/find.html

Use /N with windows Find.

For example:

```
FIND /N "Jones" names.txt
```

Comment: How does the line number help?

Comment: Any good reputable editor will give you the ability to look on line 300401 - while you can look for a string of johndoe, sometimes line number is helpful.  There is a gotcha here using Windows Notepad for example, it does not handle unix or mac new line entries properly.

Comment: ok, I'll reformulate: How does the line number help in the given situation here?

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I went and re-read the title of the post: "Batch file to search for string and return line".  Re-reading this would echo back or echo to a result file.  I mis-read the post as being the poster was looking for line number.