# Print line if contains word

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to execute a few things for me. 
Now I do understand a few programming languages, but I haven't done much in batch file programming yet.

I am starting simple. 
I need a batch file to read in a file and read through it line by line. 
If the line contains the word "node" I would like to have the line printed in my command prompt.

file1 = the file I read in that was given by the user. 
That part works.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%file1%) do (
    REM Find the lines that contain: node
    if exist "node" in %%l (
        echo %%l
    )
    REM for %%i in ('findstr "node" %%l') do (
        REM echo %%l
    REM )
)
```

The part that I commented out I also tried. 
But both of them don't work. 
It stil return all lines the whole time.

Can anyone give me a hint on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just `findstr /i "node" %file1%`?

Comment: But if I find it how do I now the line is true for that word in it?

Comment: That seems to do the trick though.

Comment: Okey, I used this: set lineNode = findstr /i "node" %file1%
Looks what I need for the next step. Thank you.

Comment: Avoid batch and switch to PowerShell.

Comment: @rojo - see my answer. I say it many times because I think the community is well-served in leaving behind cmd.exe shell scripting in favor of a superior technology (PowerShell).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Yep, I removed my comment when I saw you had answered.  I'll concede that PowerShell is more powerful than pure batch, but it's also much slower and not always the best tool for the job.

Comment: @rojo - It may be slower in some specific cases, but there is an overall net gain in productivity.

Comment: There's an overall gain in user frustration from having to wait for powershell to load.  :)

Comment: I load the PowerShell console once per session, after I log on. Slight delay at the beginning, full day of productivity after that. :)

Comment: I want to thank the both of you for the answers. I like both options. What I did is install CygWin so i can run Unix scripts as well. Now I can use grep and stuff to retrieve the words I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to output the matching line with no logic checking, do

```
findstr /i "node" "%file1%"
```

If you want to execute some code if the line is found, use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).

```
findstr /i "node" "%file1%" && (

    rem File contained "node".  Do some stuff.

) || (

    rem File did not contain "node".  Do something else.

)
```

And if you want to use `findstr` to test for the existence of a string without actually dumping the result to the console, simply add `>NUL` either before or after the `findstr` command.

```
>NUL findstr /i "node" "%file1%" && (success) || fail
```

Comment: This looks like what I can use for it. It is that we have a file that I am looking lines that start with "node". In those lines there is information that I need to retieve.: id="TextId1" We need to look if the ID's are all unique. 

Is there also a simple way to retieve the "TextId1" from a line? Like that it is not taking the other: visible="blabla"? 

I do program in PLSQL and XML for my work. I work there for a year now. This is completly new for me again. But as far as I see now I like to setup. Very efficient. (I recently started with this in Unix for our databases.)

Comment: If you're used to *nix tools, you could install GnuWin32 and restore your ability to use tools such as `sed`, `grep`, `less`, `sort`, and so forth.  Easiest solution would be to use `grep -o` to retrieve the ID.  To scrape the value using pure batch, you should put some example content in your question.  It'll have to be separated with `for` loops.  Generally speaking, capturing the output of any command in batch involves `for /f`.  Type `help for` in a console window for details.

Comment: @Tenzin - PowerShell can retrieve substring matches. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to scripting, I would avoid batch (shell script) and use PowerShell. PowerShell is far more powerful and flexible.

```
get-content 'file.txt' | select-string 'node:(\s+)' | foreach-object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
}
```

This command would output the first substring match (from inside parentheses in regular expression) from each line.

Comment: I will have a look after that power shell as well.

Comment: Bill, see OP's comment below my answer.  PowerShell is becoming the correct tool for the job, it appears.

Comment: I think both Unix and Powershell have things what would make them the best choice. I will do more research on it tommorow. And I will try both options. :-) Thanks for mentioning it. Never heared of it before.