# Extract specific information from a log file using a script (Linux or Windows or Python)

Tags: python, bash, batch-file, logging

I am interested in learning how to extract information

- **count occurrences** of keywords,
- **get the timestamp** for specific occurrences of keywords (note that the timestamps will always for the same day; usually, within a couple of hours of the same day),
- **get the elapsed time** of specific log entries

from a text log file (`log.txt`) via a *script* (**Linux bash** or **Windows batch** or **Python**). All this information should be written in another text file (`results.txt`) or be printed on the terminal.

*Basically, all the other log entries (i.e. with the `blah blah` are ignored).*

For example for the following text log file, where each line starts with a *timestamp* followed by an *empty space*, a *dash line*(-) and one or more *empty space(s)* followed by keywords:

> 11:59:35.875 - action - WRITE(34) start
>
> 11:59:35.875 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:35.875 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:35.877 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:35.897 - KEYWORD_1
>
> 11:59:35.975 - action - WRITE(34) end
>
> 11:59:36.992 - KEYWORD_1
>
> 11:59:36.999 - KEYWORD_1
>
> 11:59:37.535 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:37.545 - ACTION_A - STATE: type 2
>
> 11:59:37.575 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:37.577 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:37.845 - KEYWORD_2
>
> 11:59:37.945 - ACTION_B result
>
> 11:59:37.950 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:38.075 - action - WRITE(22) start
>
> 11:59:38.075 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:38.085 - blah blah
>
> 11:59:38.097 - KEYWORD_2
>
> 11:59:39.975 - action - WRITE(22) end

Firstly, I would like to count the occurrences of each of the `KEYWORD_1` and the `KEYWORD_2` (e.g. 2 and 2, respectively).

Secondly, I want to be able to print the timestamps of each `KEYWORD` occurrence, e.g. `11:59:35.897` for the first occurrence of the `KEYWORD_1`.

Finally, find the elapsed time between two log entries:

1. those who start with `- action - WRITE(#) start` and end with `- action - WRITE(#) end` where `#` is any integer number, e.g. 11:59:35.975 - 11:59:35.875 = `1ms` for the first `WRITE(34)`
2. those who start with `- ACTION_A ...` and end with `ACTION_B ...` e.g. 11:59:37.545 - 11:59:37.945 = `4ms` for the first `ACTION_A .. ACTION_B`.

I have tried `find /c "KEYWORD_1" log.txt >results.txt` (Windows batch) to count the occurrences but I cannot extract the respective timestamp. For the other requirements I have no idea how to start as I have no experience with such actions before. Tried adapting the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107555/how-to-extract-rows-from-a-log-file-using-windows-command-line-tools-or-batch-fi) for my needs with no success.

Any code fragment example or link with related resources will be much appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question, you should consider searching for parsing text files in a batch script.

Comment: Also, using Linux bash should be easier (?), although I am not skilled enough to give a solution.

Comment: Instead of spending time trying to fulfill your complex requirements with batch I'd try learning powershell or maybe LogParser. Aside from this with only timestamps it might be difficult to get elapsed tme when overlapping a day.

Comment: I understand the challenge, so I edited the question to include more possible solution scripts; windows batch, linux bash or Python.

Comment: @LotPings I should clarify that the timestamps will always for the same day (usually, within a couple of hours of the same day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40441783.txt"
:: occurrence count for KEYWORD_1,KEYWORD_2,KEYWORD_3
FOR %%k IN (KEYWORD_1 KEYWORD_2 KEYWORD_3) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN ('type "%filename1%"^|FIND /c "%%k"') DO ECHO %%k : %%c times
)
:: Timestamp display for KEYWORD_1,KEYWORD_2,KEYWORD_3
FOR %%k IN (KEYWORD_1 KEYWORD_2 KEYWORD_3) DO (
 type "%filename1%"|FIND "%%k"
)
:: remove variables starting $ or #
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: action - WRITE(#)
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=- " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM interested in "pattern - WRITE(#) start/end"
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3*delims=-()" %%A IN ("%%b") DO (
  REM %%A is action, %%B "WRITE" %%C # %%D " start"/" end"
  IF "%%B"==" WRITE" IF "%%D"==" start" SET "$%%C %%A$=%%a"
  IF "%%B"==" WRITE" IF "%%D"==" end" SET "#%%C %%A#=%%a"
  CALL :formatch&CALL :report "WRITE(%%C)"
 )
)
SET $ 2>nul
SET # 2>nul
:: remove variables starting $ or #
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=- " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM interested in "ACTION_A/ACTION_B elapsed time"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=- " %%A IN ("%%b") DO (
  REM %%A is action, %%B remainder of line
  IF "%%A"=="ACTION_A" SET "$1$=%%a"&SET "_actiona=%%B"
  IF "%%A"=="ACTION_B" SET "#1#=%%a"
  CALL :formatch
  CALL :report "%%_actiona%% %%B"
 )
)
SET $ 2>nul
SET # 2>nul

GOTO :EOF


:: See whether a $something$ AND a #something# exist and report if so
:formatch
SET "elapsed="
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=$=" %%m IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO (
 IF DEFINED #%%m# (
  CALL :elapsed %%n %%#%%m#%%
  SET "#%%m#="
  SET "$%%m$="
 )
)
GOTO :eof

:report
IF DEFINED elapsed ECHO %elapsed% %~1
GOTO :eof

:: get %2 - %1 both in HH:mm.ss.ttt format
:elapsed
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=:." %%w IN ("%2") DO (SET /a hh=2%%w&SET /a mm=2%%x&SET /a ss=2%%y&SET /a ttt=2%%z)
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=:." %%w IN ("%1") DO (SET /a hh-=1%%w&SET /a mm-=1%%x&SET /a ss-=1%%y&SET /a ttt-=1%%z)
:: compensate for "negatives"
IF %ttt% lss 1000 set/a ttt+=1000&set/a ss-=1
IF %ss% lss 100 set/a ss+=60&set/a mm-=1
IF %mm% lss 100 set/a mm+=60&set/a hh-=1
IF %hh% lss 100 set/a hh+=24
SET "elapsed=%hh:~-2%:%mm:~-2%:%ss:~-2%.%ttt:~-3%"
GOTO :eof

GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.
I used a file named `q40441783.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Interesting exercise.

The first two steps are fairly obvious. I included `KEYWORD_3` to ensure a correct report was produced for "not found". Note that you state 2 occurrences for KEYWORD_1. Actually, in your posted data there are 3.

The next step required some explanation. First thing I do is to ensure that there are no variables starting `#` or `$`.

Next- analyse each line, splitting first on the first `-` or <kbd>Space</kbd> and then processing the part beyond the first delimiter-sequence tokenising on `-()` so that the tokens are as described in the `REM` statement. We then set the variable `$...$` or `#...#` to the time in `%%a`. `...` here is the unique part of the log entry - the number and action. Then check whether there is both a `$...$` and `#...#` for the same `...` and if so, clear the `$#...$#` variables, calculate the elapsed time, reconstruct the line and report.

The elapsed-time calculation prepends 2 to the start of each  of the variables to ensure that they don't start `0` and potentially get treated as octal. Then pull the same trick with subtracting the start time, using a prepended 1 to produce a result that should be 3 digits (4 for ms). If fewer digits are detected, then we need to add an appropriate number and deduct one from the next-higher time element.

The processing for the action_a/_b timing is essentially the same, but records the start/end times in $!$/#1# since there is no indication of the nature of the strings `action_a` and `action_b` and we're forced to assume that the appropriate events don't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it looks it isn't such a difficult task, I took it as a challenge.
I use internal `for /f` and `findstr.exe` for parsing. (Done:The sub :Procline needs some more work for time calculation.)

Keywords.txt:

```
action
KEYWORD_1
ACTION_A
KEYWORD_2
ACTION_B
```

Batchfile

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Log=LogFile.txt
Set Key=Keywords.txt
For /f "tokens=1-5* delims=-() " %%A in (
  'findstr /i /G:%Key% %Log% ^|Sort /+16'
) Do call :ProcLine "%%A" %%B %%C %%D %%E
Echo Count
set _
Pause 
Goto :Eof

:ProcLine
Set /A _%2+=1
Echo %~1 - %2 %3 %4 %5
:: Do we need to calc times? 
Echo %5 | findstr /i "end start" >Nul 2>&1 || Goto :Eof
Call :CalcMsecs %1 x%5
If /i %5 neq start Goto :Eof
Set /a xElap=xend-xstart
If %xElap% gtr 0 Echo Elapsed Time: %xElap% msec
Goto :Eof

:CalcMsecs
Setlocal&Set T=%~1
Set /A _h=%T:~0,2%,_m=%T:~3,2%,_s=%T:~6,2%,_ms=%T:~9,3%
Set /A _m+=_h*60
Set /A _s+=_m*60
Set /A _ms+=_s*1000
:: set _
Endlocal&Set %2=%_ms%&Goto :Eof
```

Output  (till now, still refining)

```
11:59:39.975 - action WRITE 22 end
11:59:38.075 - action WRITE 22 start
Elapsed Time: 1914 msec
11:59:35.975 - action WRITE 34 end
11:59:35.875 - action WRITE 34 start
Elapsed Time: 100 msec
11:59:37.545 - ACTION_A STATE: type 2
11:59:37.945 - ACTION_B result
11:59:36.992 - KEYWORD_1
11:59:35.897 - KEYWORD_1
11:59:36.999 - KEYWORD_1
11:59:38.097 - KEYWORD_2
11:59:37.845 - KEYWORD_2
Count
_action=6
_ACTION_A=1
_ACTION_B=1
_KEYWORD_1=3
_KEYWORD_2=2
```

There is a flaw with 14 msec comming from nowhere, but it's too late for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is python option:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

keywords = ['KEYWORD_1', 'KEYWORD_2']
actions = ['WRITE(']
kws_dict = {}
acts_dict = {}

with open('sample.log') as l:
    with open('filtered.log', 'w') as f:
        for line in l:
            if any(k in line for k in keywords) and len(line) > 1:
                entry = line.split('-')[1].strip()
                dt = line.split('-')[0].strip()
                if entry in kws_dict:
                    kws_dict[entry].append(datetime.strptime(dt, '%H:%M:%S.%f'))
                else:
                    kws_dict[entry] = [datetime.strptime(dt,'%H:%M:%S.%f')]
            elif any(a in line for a in actions) and len(line) > 1:
                dt = line.split('-')[0].strip()
                action = line.split(' ')[-2].strip()
                action_type = line.split(' ')[-1].strip()
                if action in acts_dict.keys():
                    acts_dict[action][action_type] = datetime.strptime(dt,'%H:%M:%S.%f')
                else:
                    acts_dict[action] = {action_type:datetime.strptime(dt,'%H:%M:%S.%f')}

# print results
for k in kws_dict.keys():
    print('%s occured %s times' % (k, len(kws_dict[k])))
# comment below if you don't need specific timestamps
    for i in kws_dict[k]:
        print('\t%s' % i.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))

#iterate over actions, then action_types (start, end)
for a, at in acts_dict.iteritems():
    print('%s: Elapsed time %s' % (a, at['end'] - at['start']))
#    for at, t in acts_dict[a].iteritems():
#        print('\t%s: %s' % (at, t.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')))

## Raw data in case you need it
#print("Actions:\n", acts_dict)
```

Which produces:

> KEYWORD_1 occured 3 times
>       11:59:35.897000
>       11:59:36.992000
>       11:59:36.999000
>   KEYWORD_2 occured 2 times
>       11:59:37.845000
>       11:59:38.097000
>   WRITE(34): Elapsed time 0:00:00.100000
>   WRITE(22): Elapsed time 0:00:01.900000

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good this will be but why don't you try to read every line and if the keyword is in it , just write it on another file .
You can try to do something like:

```
with open('log.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'KEYWORD' in line:
            with open('results.txt','a') as z:
                z.write(line)
```

Comment: I like this approach. Could you also include some ideas on how to proceed to extract the timestamps for each match? Should I use regular expressions?

Comment: Well , if you know that the timestamps will always be 12 characters long you can do something with line[:13]--->This will "take" the first 12 characters and you can paste them somewhere.

Comment: I see. But then, how will I also handle the elapsed time for the 2 possible matching log entries (start and end)? If you could put together a rough script to show both that would be great!